# Why are all the lines returned by `svn blame Foo.cs` blank?

Tags: svn, properties, binary

I have a file in my Subversion repository named "Foo.cs".  When I run the command `svn blame Foo.cs` the output looks something like this:

```
1000 dave 
1000 dave
2000 dave
2000 dave
9999 dave
1000 dave
9999 dave
```

The only thing that I can think of is that from revisions 1000-9000, Foo.cs had the "svn:mime-type" property set to "application/octet-stream".  However, since r9000 Foo.cs has no such property since it is (and always has been) a text file.

Also, I've already tried to use `svn blame Foo.cs --force` without success.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

EDIT: At r1000, the history was truncated (`svn log Foo.cs` doesn't report anything earlier than this) because the branch was moved to a different spot in the repository by hand instead of using `svn mv`.  However, it's hard to imagine that this is the cause of the problem because `svn blame` works on every other file in the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only thing that I can think of is that from revisions 1000-9000, Foo.cs had the "svn:mime-type" property set to "application/octet-stream". However, since r9000 Foo.cs has no such property since it is (and always has been) a text file.

I think that's your answer.  Experimenting with Subversion 1.6, any time I have a revision in history with `svn:mime-type` set to `application/octet-stream`, I get `Skipping binary file` from `svn blame`.

Subversion [may have set the property automatically](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.props.auto), if it detected the file as having non-text content.

I can't think of a good answer to fix the situation.  You can delete and re-add the file again.  This will truncate history, but at least `svn blame` will work for newer revisions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find your answer by looking at what happened in change numbers 9999 and 2000. Or, simply look at all the changes for the file (`svn -log -v Foo.cs`) and see if any other properties might have been changed.